# Do I have to use delete to avoid memory leaks? I have used new to allocate the structure instances

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, destructor

The following code is implementing a simple hash function. I have allocated the struct instances with the `new` operator.

Do I have use the `delete` operator when the program ends?

If so, how do I do it? [ A `delete` statement for each of the instances of the struct? Or is there an easier way of doing it? ]

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 10

using namespace std;

typedef struct myhashtag
{
   int data;
   struct myhashtag * next;
} myhash;
void printhash(myhash array[])
{
// print fn
}

void hash(int data, myhash array[])
{
   int h = data % SIZE;
   myhash * newhash = new myhash;
   newhash->data = data;
   newhash->next = NULL;

   if(array[h].next == NULL)  //first insert
   {
      array[h].next = newhash;
      return;
   }
   myhash * iter = array[h].next;
   while(iter->next != NULL)
   {
      iter = iter->next;
   }
   iter->next = newhash;
   return;
}


int main()
{
   myhash array[SIZE];int i;
   for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
   {
      array[i].data = 0;
      array[i].next = NULL;
   }

   while(1)
   {
      cout << "\nSo, what would you like to enter? : ";
      cin >> i;
      hash(i, array);
      printhash(array);
   }

// the deletes go here 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every `new()` issued should have an accompanying `delete` statement. _'A `delete` statement for each of the instances of the struct?'_ Yes, besides those created automatically with `myhash array[SIZE];`.

Comment: when you are dealing with big project, you need to use `delete` for every `new` operator!. otherwise you will run out of memory!

Comment: But really you should be using a memory management device like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) so that `new` and `delete` aren't needed.

Comment: @Sathish if one could downvote comments, I would downvote yours just for the first sentence. That's just bad practice, and might get people into the habit of always forgetting it. Also, some projects might start as small applications and unexpectedly be (re-)used for larger ones. And then you have the maintenance nightmare of tracking down all dynamic allocations...

Comment: @anderas Actually, his statement is 100% correct.  Smart pointers are one way of doing this, which is in some cases a good solution (but probably not here---he needs to wrap his hash table in a larger function which manages its memory).

Comment: @JamesKanze that referred to his comment before the edit. There, he advised that in small projects, deleting allocated memory wasn't necessary. (Is there a way of viewing old versions of comments?)

Answer (score 3):

In general, you will indeed need to perform a delete (or delete[] for arrays) once for each allocation with new.

If you are on linux, valgrind can help detect memory leaks, by the way.

Recent versions of C++, as well as the Boost library, provided various sorts of smart pointers, which basically will free the memory automatically when the object is no longer referenced.

Lookup std::unique_ptr in your C++ book of choice.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to use any libraries, actually. And Boost will definitely "boost" up the size of my executable! [off-topic]
 Anyways, a `delete` in the same way as `new` should do the job, I reckon?

Comment: @sigmasquared _'But I don't want to use any libraries'_ You don't need to, unless the c++ standard library counts as such for you.

Comment: Yes, it would, but it sometimes is quite hard to know when you need to delete. You will have to properly document in your code whether the caller or the callee is responsible for freeing memory. One convention is to use references when the memory still belongs to the caller, and pointers when the callee takes ownership.

Comment: @0x499602D2 @manuBriot Thanks for leading me to `unique_ptr`. Checking it out currently.

Comment: None of the usual smart pointers handle cycles.  And given what he seems to be doing, none of them are really appropriate.

Comment: On looking at his code again, for this simple case, `std::unique_ptr` would actually do the trick.  It would get more complicated if he decided at a later date to rehash, in order to change the size; globally, it's usually preferable in such cases to wrap the table in a class, and let it manage the memory.

Comment: That's correct. The standard smart pointers use reference counting, which means indeed that a cycle means that no memory will be reclaimed. Other languages have garbage collectors that can deal with such cycles, but not C++. Often, using the standard STL containers makes it much easier to handle memory management. It is also possible to allocate all memory in a pool, and free all the pool at once rather than each element separately (with code similar to    a = new(pool) Data)

Comment: @manuBriot "Other languages have garbage collectors that can deal with such cycles": so does C++.  Just not as part of the standard.  The Boehm collector can be an excellent solution for some types of applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should always delete any dynamic memory which you allocate.

You could implement a simple RAII container to handle your memory cleanup. Just create a class to act as a handle which news the memory in its constructor. deletes it inside its destructor and provides some kind of access mechanism. That way any memory is automatically cleaned up at the end of the scope in which the handleis declared in.

Comment: Any other way of doing it without classes? I guess I have to do it by rote, iterating through all the elements and deleting them, from the front end, to be faster.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use classes? The only real difference between a c++ class and a struct is the default access level. a struct defaults to public and a class to private. So you could do the same with a struct.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does require you to manage the lifetime of objects.  It's not nearly as hard as many Java or C# books might lead you to believe.  But, yes, without using a [garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), you need to be sure that `delete` gets called appropriately.

There are two ways I can imagine doing this for the code you posted.  The first is, as others have suggested, to use `std::unique_ptr`.

The second is to give your `struct` a destructor.  I'm not really clear why you use the classic C `typedef struct ...`  idiom (you do that in C so that you don't have to use the `struct` keyword as often, but you don't have to use the `struct` keyword as often in C++).  I'll keep it in the code that follows, but I want to flag it as nonidiomatic:

```
typedef struct myhashtag
{
   int data;
   struct myhashtag * next;

   ~myhashtag()
   {
      if (next) {
         delete next;
      }
   }
} myhash;
```

(You still need to be sure to `delete` the head node where you put the comment that "deletes happen here").

However, this assumes that `next` is correctly assigned to `NULL` when it's the end of the list.  The code you posted does that, but it's only enforced by convention.  A slightly more idiomatic approach would be:

```
struct hash_node {
   int data;
   hash_node* next;

   hash_node(int d, n = NULL) : data(d), next(n) { }

   ~hash_node()
   {
      if (next) {
         delete next;
      }
   }
};

void hash(int data, hash_node* array)
{
   int h = data % SIZE;
   hash_node* newhash = new hash_node(data);

   if(array[h].next == NULL)  //first insert
   {
      array[h].next = newhash;
      return;
   }
   hash_node* iter = array[h].next;
   while(iter->next != NULL)
   {
      iter = iter->next;
   }
   iter->next = newhash;
   return;
}
```

A much more idiomatic approach would be:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std'

int main()
{
    list<int> list_that_the_code_was_calling_a_hash;
    while(1) {
        cout << "\nSo, what would you like to enter? : ";
        cin >> i;
        list_that_the_code_was_calling_a_hash.push_back(i);
        if (list_that_the_code_was_calling_a_hash.size() > 10) {
            list_that_the_code_was_calling_a_hash.pop_front();
        }
        printhash(list_that_the_code_was_calling_a_hash);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And many people would recommend using a `std::vector` because `std::list` simply doesn't interact well with your CPU cache.  Yes, `std::vector` does a lot more copying when you muck witht he middle of the container.  But it more than makes up for that by being very cache friendly.